# Is it ok to stop execution of async route handler with return statement in an Express app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an async route handler like this one:

```
router.post('/', async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const { username, email, password } = req.body
    const { errors, userData } = validateRegistrationInput(username, email, password)
    if (errors) {
      res.status(422).render('register', {
        registrationErrors: errors,
      })
      return
    }
    // I don't want to run anything if errors == true
    // Continue running if no errors
  } catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
})
```

Is it ok to stop a route handler with a `return` statement in Express app this way? I understand that if I return from an async function, a Promise object will be returned. But, it will be simply garbage collected in this case, right?

Comment: Generally yes, in the sense that all functions return - but if you don't want to send a response or delegate to `next` then you should at least call `res.end()` after the if statement to close the connection, else the client may hang.

Comment: @Emissary Thanks,  I was thinking that I didn't need to `res.end()` after `res.status().render()` but  it looks like  I was wrong.

Comment: @Emissary - `res.render()`, `res.send()`, `res.sendStatus()` and a few other calls already do the `res.end()` for you.  It is actually a programming mistake to call `res.end()` again.

Comment: Why are you even making your route handler `async`?  There is no use of `await` here which is the usual reason why you make something `async`.

Comment: @jfriend00 it's just a small part of the code.  I'm using `await` latter on when code continues to execute if `errors==false`

Comment: @jfriend00 re-read it - if you were to return early as in the example provided the code can reach a point where nothing flushes the response. `res.end()` **is** required after that `if` block if the intent is for the handler to do nothing - it is bad practice to leave the response hanging.

Comment: @Emissary - This is only partial code.  The OP does send a response in the `else` per their other comments.  There is no need to use `res.end()` with `res.status().render()`.  The return early shown in this code does NOT need a `res.end()` with it because the response has already been sent and ended there.  Maybe you meant something else with your comment, but that was not clear to me.  Read my answer and the OP's comments to it to see the rest of the discussion.

Comment: Nobody suggested there was a need to call both, this is a straw man. The question doesn't indicate that anything is guaranteed to be written to the response stream, I'm merely pointing out that _something_ should end it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it ok to stop execution of async route handler with return statement in an Express app?

Yes, it is perfectly fine.  Express itself isn't paying any attention to the promise returned from your `async` function so you are under no obligation to resolve that promise with some particular value.   When your desired code flow dictates, you can stop further processing of the route handler with `return` at any time.

> I understand that if I return from an async function, a Promise object will be returned. But, it will be simply garbage collected in this case, right?

Yes, that is correct.  The promise will be garbage collected.

---

A few other observations about this request handler.

1. If there are no errors, this request handler just leaves the request hanging, never sending a response.  All paths through the code should either send a response or forward the request to other code that will send a response.  In your case if `errors` is truthy, then you never send any response.
2. There does not appear to be any reason for you to declare this route handler `async` as there is no use of `await`.

Comment: @Noob - See the additional comments I added onto the answer.

Comment: It's just a small part of relevant code regarding my question. I use  `await` later on. Also there is more logic in this function.

Comment: @Noob - OK, got it.